# C++, set bool to false, return old

Tags: c++, boolean, conditional-operator

This code:

```
bool b = isTrue;
isTrue = false;
```

saves old `isTrue` value to `b`, then sets `isTrue` to `false`. All good, but is there a way to perform this in one line? In the end I would like to achieve this:

```
bool b = isTrue ? /* assign true and flip `isTrue` value to false */ : false;
```

Comment: Why do you need in one line? The compiler will translate to most optimized code,

Comment: Your last line of code seems to contradict the initial requirement -- if `isTrue` starts off as false then `: false` doesn't make any attempt to flip `isTrue`

Comment: @M.M yea, I would like to only flip `true` case to `false` and leave `false` case as it is. With ternary operator I (unfortunately) need to write it all in one line

Comment: But you started the post by saying it should do `isTrue = !isTrue;` in all cases. Please edit the post to clarify .  Maybe what you actually want is `bool b = isTrue; isTrue = false;` ?

Comment: @M.M yes, correct. I would like that...

Comment: OK, I've edited, if that does not correctly show your intentions then please rollback and/or edit to do so

Comment: yeah looks like your luck took a turn for the worse

Answer (score 3):

[`std::exchange`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange) can be used to do exactly this:

```
bool b = std::exchange(isTrue, !isTrue);
```

It's equivalent to:

```
bool b = (isTrue := !isTrue)
```

Where `:=` is a magical assignment operator that returns the old value rather than the freshly-assigned value.

---

If you instead would like `b` to have the old value of `isTrue` and set `isTrue` to `false`, as the discussion in the comments suggests, you can do this with:

```
bool b = std::exchange(isTrue, false);
```

Comment: OP changed their requirements (or perhaps, didn't explain them very well in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

it'll be

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    bool t = !false;
    bool b = false;
//  b = t, t = !t; 
    t = !(b = t); 
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "b : " << b << " , " << "t : " << t << " . " << "give me a bottle of rum!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

line that's comented works too